# HTMLXPathSelector for Scrappy returning null results

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I just started learning python / Scrapy. I was able to follow tutorials successfully but I am struggling with a 'test' scraping that I want to do on my own.

What I am trying to do now is go on http://jobs.walmart.com/search/finance-jobs and scrape the job listing.

However, I think I may be doing something wrong in the XPath, but I am not sure what.

There is no "id" for that table, so I am using its class.

```html
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector


class MySpider(BaseSpider):
  name = "walmart"
  allowed_domains = ["jobs.walmart.com"]
  start_urls = ["http://jobs.walmart.com/search/finance-jobs"]

  def parse(self, response):
      hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
      titles = hxs.select("//table[@class='tableSearchResults']")
      items = []
      for titles in titles:
          item = walmart()
          item ["title"] = titles.select("a/text()").extract()
          item ["link"] = titles.select("a/@href").extract()
          items.append(item)
      return items
```

here is what the page source looks like:

Answer (score 0):

The problem as you said also, is your XPATH. It is always useful to run:

```
scrapy view http://jobs.walmart.com/search/finance-jobs
```

Before running your spider, to see how the website look like from scrapy view.

This should work now:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector


class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "walmart"
    allowed_domains = ["jobs.walmart.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://jobs.walmart.com/search/finance-jobs"]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item = walmart()
        titles = hxs.select("//table[@class='tableSearchResults']/tr")
        items = []
        for title in titles:
            if title.select("td[@class='td1']/a").extract():
                item ["title"] = title.select("td[@class='td1']/a/text()").extract()
                item ["link"] = title.select("td[@class='td1']/a/@href").extract()
                items.append(item)
        return items
```

Comment: I'll let you know how this goes tonight!

Comment: When I run the command:
scrapy crawl walmart -o items.csv -t csv
A file of type csv is created, but there are no results in it. it is a blank file. am I missing something?

Comment: Try this (scrapy crawl walmart -o items.json) if you can see the results. then you can export it to csv file

Comment: The JSON file returned is also empty.

Comment: You are doing something wrong somewhere in your code. I ran this code and I have the result.
try to replace (`item ["title"] =`, `item ["link"] =`) with `print`, and just call `scrapy crawl walmart`, you should have the output and you will see that is working